# Java - How to move element in Array to another Array?

Tags: java, arrays, element, move

I made this code:

```
Integer []array=new Integer[999];
   Integer []dump=new Integer[999];  
    for( int i=0;xconv!=0;++i){//ignore this

      array[i]=xconv%2;//ignore this
xconv=xconv/2;//ignore this
 System.out.println("array= "+array[i]+" xconv= "+xconv);//ignore this

   if(array[i]==null){//<<<<<<look here

   array[i]=ArrayUtils.toArray(dump, i);//<<<<<<<<<<<<<look here

 }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));//<<<<<<look here
```

I want the IF structure to move the element which have null values to another array named "dump", because if I dont do so, it keeps showing a bunch of "null" values when it reads the last line. I tried using ArrayUtils.toArray but netbeans keeps saying Im using it wrongly. How should I do that and make it show only elements that actually has some value inside? Thanks

Comment: You can't move the elements which are null, they're null because there is no element there.

Comment: `new Integer[999]` creates an array of 999 references to `Integer` objects, all of which start with the default value of `null`.  Are you sure you want an array of `Integer` and not an array of `int`?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how toArray works. Check the JavaDoc:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toArray%28T...%29

Comment: yeah I found that out now xD

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand what arrays are or how they work.
An array is a fixed-length data structure.
Each index in that array may contain a value, or may be null.

It sounds like what you are looking for is a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is a data structure which is dynamically sized (it grows and shrinks as you add and remove elements).

When you iterate over a `List` you will only see the elements it currently holds, as opposed to an array, where you will need to traverse its length and check each entry to see if there is a value there or not.

If you're married to using arrays for your calculation, you can still easily convert them to `Lists` for the purpose of display.

Instead of this:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));//<<<<<<look here
```

Try this:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however that code didnt work for me, the nulls still keep showing. I gonna change it to a List then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just print the range that you care about:

```
    int[] array = new int[999];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; xconv != 0; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = xconv % 2;
        xconv = xconv / 2;
        System.out.println("array= " + array[i] + " xconv= " + xconv);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(array, i)));
```

Even better, use an `ArrayList`:

```
    List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; xconv != 0; ++i)
    {
        array.add(xconv % 2);
        xconv = xconv / 2;
        System.out.println("array= " + array.get(i) + " xconv= " + xconv);
    }
    System.out.println(array.toString());
```